# Почему passthru(), system() и exec() возвращают значение "126"?

Tags: c, php

При вызове passthru(), system() и exec() я получаю значение 126 вместо того, что выводит команда.

Исходный код скрипта PHP:

```
<?php
system("parser  1  /var/www/checklinks/data/test.txt",$output);
echo $output;
?>
```

Исходный код команды (С):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *in;
    char c = ' ';
    char *m;
    m = argv[1];
    unsigned long int count = 0;

    in = fopen(argv[2], "r");
    if (strcmp(argv[1], "1") == 0) {
        while (!feof(in)) {
            fscanf(in, "%c", &c);
            if (c == '\n')
                count++;
        }
    }
    if (strcmp(argv[1], "2") == 0) {
        while (!feof(in)) {
            fscanf(in, "%c", &c);
            if (c != '\n') {
                if (c != ' ')
                    count++;
            }
        }
    }

    fclose(in);
    printf("%d", count);
}
```

Как сделать так, что бы функции возвращали то, что возвращает программа ?

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Быстренько сваял hello_world и при тестах понял что
 1. Нужен полный путь.
 2. Если программа возвращает не ноль, то у меня выводился какой-то мусор (127 и 173), и ноль, если программа вернет ноль
 3. Любой вывод в программе (printf || cout точно) записывается в переменную $output

Comment: Я закинул parser в /bin

Comment: Лично у меня в тестах все выводилось верно только когда был прописан осмысленный путь к программе parser. Результат возвращал через return.

Answer (score 1):

Для того чтобы получить в $output ответ программы, программа должна этот ответ передать. Для этого в конце программы нужно возвратить ответ в виде кода выполнения программы:

```
fclose(in);
return count;
}
```

Comment: Добавил, не помогло :-(
Скрипт возвращает - 126

Comment: Вы заменили строку printf("%d", count) на return count? Еще стоило бы попробовать вручную запустить из консоли parser. Вполне возможно, что для нормального запуска надо записать в программе хотя бы относительный путь, типа system("./parser ...

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена.
Необходимо было сделать chmod 755 на программу.
Спасибо всем, кто откликнулся и попытался мне помочь!